# Jersey + Jetty + Gradle 404 Error - but works in Tomcat

Tags: gradle, jersey, jetty

Trying to add the Jetty Gradle plugin to a current project. My war works fine with a Tomcat deploy, but Jetty seems to blow up with 404 errors -- as if it's not reading the web.xml correctly (verified that its there).

localhost:8080/rest/test  <- works in Tomcat

localhost:8080/rest/test  <- 404 when running jettyRun(war) in Gradle

My simplified Code (Java)

```
package testPackage;
//includes...
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testResponse() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1"
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19'
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>testPackage</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Yep, works in Tomcat -- change it to that for simplification. Updated the sample to point to a package directly, but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was needed in my build.grade:

```
jettyRun.contextPath = ''
```